# How to run react-native example on github

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie of react-native.
I have read document in: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html#examples

And my question is: how to run file ButtonExample.js in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/ButtonExample.js

I tried to set up something in "index.android.js" file:
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';
import {examples} from './examples';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('examples', () => examples);
```

```
But it did not work.
Sorry my English is bad.
Thank for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the errors?

Do you meet the required react-native version? `react-native -version`

Did you type `npm install` in the working directory?

Could you define "run file" ButtonExample.js?

Running a react-native project requires a mobile emulator or a mobile device.

Comment: I writed a file name ButtonExample.js in this project, and in file index.android.js I import it with code:
import {ButtonExample} from './ButtonExample';
And i registed:
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ButtonExample', () => ButtonExample);
My project name: ButtonTest

Comment: How are you running the project? Where is it not working? Could you paste the error?